# How to round up or down when converting f32 to bf16 in rust?

Tags: rust, rounding, half-precision-float

I am converting from `f32` to `bf16` in rust, and want to control the direction of the rounding error. Is there an easy way to do this?

Converting using the standard `bf16::to_f32` rounds to the *nearest* bf16 value, which can be either larger or smaller than the original:

```
use half::bf16;
fn main() {
    for x in vec![0.1_f32, 0.11, 0.12] {
        let xh = bf16::from_f32(x);
        let diff = x - bf16::to_f32(xh);
        println!("{}, {}, {}",  x, bf16::from_f32(x), diff)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.1, 0.100097656, -0.00009765476
0.11, 0.10986328, 0.00013671815
0.12, 0.12011719, -0.00011719018
```

Comment: Only the documentation of `half` can tell you that, and it doesn't seem like it supports bespoke rounding modes. Either way, this is something which should be discussed with and reported to the crate maintainer.

Comment: The `bf16` type is implemented purely in software. It's basically an `f32` with the significand truncated to eight bits. It doesn't look like the `half` crate supports any other rounding mode, so you either need to convince the author of the crate to implement that, or implement it yourself. The conversion function does [some simple bit twiddling](https://docs.rs/half/2.1.0/src/half/bfloat/convert.rs.html#4-22), so it's not difficult to implement this yourself.